# Python Dataflow to Move data from BQ to Cloud SQL

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm writing a Python Dataflow to move the data from BigQuery to Cloud SQL. I have implemented that like below. The idea is, will fetch records from BQ, then create Tuples by mapping BQ row to schema class and last step is to write to Cloud SQL using prepared statements.

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)      
        (
            p
            | 'Read from BigQuery' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query = sql_select_query, use_standard_sql=True)
            | 'Transform to NamedTuple' >> beam.Map(lambda X: beam.Row(
                COL_1=int(X['COL_1']),
                COL_2=str(X['COL_2']))).with_output_types(BQ_Table_Schema)
            | 'Write to Cloud SQL' >> WriteToJdbc(
                driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
                jdbc_url=jdbs_url,
                table_name=sql_tbl,
                username=sql_use,
                password=sql_pwd,
            
                statement=insert_query1
                )
        )
```

We plan to use this as a generic thing, could you please tell me how I can make the "Transform to NamedTuple" step more generic? For example, it one table has 3 columns it should map 3, similar if we have 5 columns all 5 should be mapped.

Thank you.!!

Comment: Do you have the NamedTuple already defined at the start of the pipeline?

Comment: No, I do not have it.

Comment: I do not think that is possible. Beam needs to know the `NamedTuples` beforehand, otherwise it has no registered coder for coding the PCollection between the different steps